# Using web components in jsps

Tags: jsp, web-component, payara

I've tried to enhance an "old" application that uses plain jsps with some web components, but it just doesn't work. Does this work at all or do I have to include the web component's javascript code somehow differently?

The application runs on Payara 5.192 with JEE7.

example.jsp

```
<head>
   <script type="module" src="<%=Globals.getProperty("DIR_JSP")%>/javascript/node_modules/my-web-component/master-detail.js" /> 
</head>

<body>
    <% funny inline java code %>
    <master-detail detailsWidth="90">My content to be shown in the details view<master-detail>
</body>
```

Comment: That can only mean the ``customElements.define`` in your ``my-detail.js`` is either not executed or is incorrect. First check if that file is loaded in the browser at all.

Answer (score 1):

The hint with "check that file is loaded in the browser" was a good one.

**The problem was not related to the custom element itself, but to my setup.** I was trying this on my local machine, so mind that the following **explanation is only for local, not production environments.**

I've deployed my javascript and the pertaining dependencies directly in the webapps folder of the application on Payara. The custom element and the pertaining dependency javascript files where all loaded on page invocation from Payara, i.d. **Payara was hit with 120 requests** which it couldn't deal with. So in fact **I did a DoS attack on my local Payara**. In the production setting I'd deploy the javascript files to nginx e.g.

After I increased the threads for the http-listener and also disabled https (as this caused high cpu spikes), it worked like charm on my local machine.